# In azure stream analytics using Tumbling Window, how to process data for the hour before last

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

So I have a stream analytics job that needs to calculate something hourly..like how long a status was 1 during the hour. The status value is coming in every 30 seconds. I am not able to use Timestamp by in my query because I am also using a cross reference command.The problem is some data is coming in late. So I want to wait 1 hour before processing the data. I was thinking I can use

```
TumblingWindow(Duration(hour, 1), Offset(hour, -1))
```

So I thought if the query runs at 8am, it will process the data that came in from 6-7am..Is that correct? But what I am seeing is, the query is still processing the data from 7-8am. 
Is my understanding of offset incorrect??

Answer (score 0):

Offset parameter is used to determine how tumbling windows are aligned. For example, by default all windows start at the beginning of the hour, but you can set offset to 30 minutes to start from the middle of the hour.
Putting whole number of hours as offset will not change behavior in your case.

I think it will be easier if you split job into two – one doing CROSS APPLY to extract events and another one which is doing temporal processing. This way you can utilize TIMESTAMP BY clause and time policies for handling late data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Splitting the job into 2 jobs will require use of another iothub and that is expensive , so I am trying these options. Will using offset(minute, -60) work or you mean to say the offset cannot be equal or larger than the window time provided??